# Convert (doublebyte) string to Hex

Tags: php, utf-8, double-byte

Let's say I have the word "Russian" written in Cyrillic. This is would be the quivalent of the following in Hex:

```
&#1056;&#1091;&#1089;&#1089;&#1082;&#1080;&#1081;
```

My question is: how do I write a function which will go from "Russian" in Cyrillic to it's hex value as above? Could this same function work also for singel byte characters?

Comment: Are you looking for [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?

Comment: That won't convert every letter, only applicable special characters.

Comment: @brad, @alien: use `htmlentities()` which should convert most characters

Comment: Doesn't work with cryllic: `echo htmlentities('русский'); // outputs Ñ€ÑƒÑÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹`

Comment: `htmlentities` converts nothing of those, [use `mb_encode_numericentity`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014791/convert-doublebyte-string-to-hex/7015137#7015137).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&#12345;` thingies are called HTML Entities. In PHP there is a function that can create these: [`mb_encode_numericentity`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php), it's part of the [Multibyte String](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ehsT1F)):

```
$cyrillic = 'русский';

$encoding = 'UTF-8';
$convmap = array(0, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff);
$encoded = mb_encode_numericentity($cyrillic, $convmap, $encoding);

echo $encoded; # &#1088;&#1091;&#1089;&#1089;&#1082;&#1080;&#1081;
```

However: You need to know the encoding of your Cyrillic string. In this case I've chosen `UTF-8`, depending on it you need to modify the `$encoding` parameter of the function and the `$convmap` array.

Answer (score 2):

Your provided example isn't hex, but if you want to convert to hex, try this:

```
function strToHex($string)
{
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
    {
        $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }
    return $hex;
}

function hexToStr($hex)
{
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2)
    {
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}

echo strToHex('русский'); // d180d183d181d181d0bad0b8d0b9
```

Comment: One note - control characters (such as \n) cause issue, so you'll need to 0-pad them by changing the " dechex(ord($string[$i])) " bit to " str_pad(dechex(ord($string[$i])), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) " in the strToHex() call. But a fantastic answer overall - thanks _very_ much for this :-)