# Storing utf8 data`मेरा भारत महान` in database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store UTF8 in database. I have data in Unicode Hindi and I want to store in MySQL database using php after converting it to HTML character sets. let's say someone enters a bullet (•) character into a text box. When saving that data, should it be converted to `&#8226;`.

Suppose I have data `मेरा भारत महान` I want to store it in database by converting it to html character. How can I do that? I tried to use htmlentities function but that doesn't work satisfactorily for me.

Comment: Why do you want to convert to entities? What is wrong with just using UTF-8?

Comment: Please define "not satisfactorily". Also seconded, what's wrong with UTF-8?

Comment: `मेरा भारत महान` stores as it is in database I want to convert it in somewhat this kind of format `&#8226;`

Comment: @Rahul but *why*? This doesn't make any sense at all. What problem is leading you to doing this? This sounds like a really dumb idea.

Answer (score 3):

The `&#8226;` thingies are called HTML Entities. In PHP there is a function that can create these: [`mb_encode_numericentity`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php), it's part of the [Multibyte String](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/32qykg)):

```
$string = 'मेरा भारत महान';
$encoding = 'UTF-8';

$convmap = array(0, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff);
$encoded = mb_encode_numericentity($string, $convmap, $encoding);

echo $encoded; &#2350;&#2375;&#2352;&#2366;&#32;&#2349;&#2366;&#2352;&#2340;&#32;&#2350;&#2361;&#2366;&#2344;
```

However: You need to know the encoding of your string. In this case I've chosen `UTF-8`, depending on it you need to modify the `$encoding` parameter of the function and the `$convmap` array.

**However, don't store it that way into your database.** Store it as-is and convert the output encoding **after** you retrieved the data from your database.

Similar Question: [Convert (doublebyte) string to Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014791/convert-doublebyte-string-to-hex)

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that doing this is probably a very dumb idea in general. (I don't mean your answer, which is fine, but the very idea of converting multibyte characters into HTML entities - my bet is the OP is having charset problems that should be fixed at their core)

Comment: Yes, I added a note that the text should not be stored with HTML entities into the database. That would be one encoding too much.

Comment: @pekka: I don't have such problem Even Ic an view my data in DB as-is rather then barcode...

Comment: @Rahul why do you want to do this then?

Comment: @pekka: Just to learn how can I achieve the task..... :D

hakre: wat does this conmap defines? pelase explain is it character range?

Comment: @Rahul Using HTML entities is *no longer necessary* if you are using UTF-8 everywhere in your application. But it's your call

Comment: I did and edited my DB to UTF-8 So I won't have any problem in future...but just for learning point of view.... I asked here... Thanks for helping...

Comment: @RahulSingh: `convmap` specifies which from all characters of a charset are being converted into numeric entities. In the example, all are converted. The numbers are hexadecimal in the example.

Answer (score 0):

`htmlentities` has a charset parameter, Try: `htmlentities($text, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")`