# PHP encoding error in view file

Tags: php, html, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decoding numeric html entities via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587751/decoding-numeric-html-entities-via-php)

I have encoding error in the breadcrumbs (view file)

how can I fix that ? php or html ?

input => **Madagascar 3: Europe's Most Wanted**

output => `Madagascar 3: Europe&#x27;s Most Wanted`

I'm using Yii PHP framework ans MySQL

[image]

Comment: why ? . how is that help me and how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this `html_entity_decode`

Here is a reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php