# In php 7.4 How do i remove special html character with acii code from string

Tags: php, html, string

I would like to decode htmlspecial charater for example `&#39;` to be transfomed as `'`

I would like to avoid making regexp.

I tried `htmlspecialchars_decode($mystring);` It works for charater such as `&agrave;` but not for one with character code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `html_entity_decode()`  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode

```php
<?php

echo html_entity_decode('&#39;');

// outputs '
```

Try it here https://3v4l.org/IcDlB

Comment: htmlspecialchars_decode works fine too (at least for this specific character code), if you have a new enough version of PHP: https://3v4l.org/10dDv

Comment: I first thought so as well, then seeing that https://stackoverflow.com/a/9587822/367456 suggested it already and found out that for both htmlspecialchars_decode() and html_entity_decode() it is not always the case for all numeric entities. Updated the answer then. E.g. on my local box with PHP 8.2 for **both** it does not translate &#39;.

Comment: I already use `htmlspecialchars_decode(html_entity_decode($mystring));` , `&#39;` are still present. As my title specify I use PHP 7.4